# cross site document.referrer is not working after chrome update

Tags: javascript

Cross site document.referrer java script is broken in chrome/new microsoft edge

Ok so when I go from this link: https://linkvertise.com/22769/abc (I put it no ads)

And I click continue

Nothing is returned for the document.referrer in chrome/new microsoft edge, it only works in internet explorer, how can I fix the problem?

The expected behavior should show

```
Document referrer testing page.
Your referrer is https://linkvertise.com/22769/abc (however this is missing)
Click this to go to https://clubdark.net/test.html
```

As you see in the print screen the referrer is missing.

My code in https://clubdark.net/test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="referrer" content="always"/>
    </head>
<body>

<b>Document referer testing page.</b>
<br>
Your referer is <b id="demo">Hello</b>
<br>
<a href="test.html">Click this to go to https://clubdark.net/test.html</a>

<script>
var a = document.referrer;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I find it may not be chrome problem because I have used document.referer on other sites and it is just that the linkvertise redirect does not work.